# Firebase database - Retrieve data from database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new firebase developer, a am developing an android app, that using firebase database.
This is a part my database.

[image]

And this is my model class:

```
public class Exam {
    private String id;
    private int subject;
    private String school;
    private Long examineDate;
    private int likeCount;
    private HashMap<String,Object> timeStampSubmit;
    public Exam(){};
    public Exam(String id, int subject, String school, Long examineDate, int likeCount) {
        this.id = id;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.school = school;
        this.examineDate = examineDate;
        this.likeCount = likeCount;
        HashMap<String, Object> timestampNowObject = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        timestampNowObject.put(Constant.FIREBASE_PROPERTY_TIMESTAMP, ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
        this.timeStampSubmit = timestampNowObject;
    }
}
```

I want to get and parse data from my database to a Exam object.

Could you give me suggestion or have any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you read [this guide - Retrieve Data on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data) ?

Example using `ValueEventListener`

```
ValueEventListener examListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Exam exam = dataSnapshot.getValue(Exam.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
};
ref.addValueEventListener(examListener);
```

Comment: Thanks. I got it. Should I remove listener when I got the value. ref.removeEventListener().

Comment: you don't need to do that, you can just use `ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(listener);` if you want to get the value once.