# Retrieving data from firebase to android studio using kotlin depending on text value

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

how to get the id of data retrieved from the firebase so I can limit the data being retrieved from the firebase depending on the id.

here is my current code, it retrieves all the data from child "beetle" on my firebase database, I want to limit that so it will show only 1 data depending on what the id is.

```
    lateinit var listView: ListView
lateinit var ref: DatabaseReference
lateinit var beetleList:MutableList<Beetle>

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_classify)

    val capturedImage = intent.extras.getParcelable("captured_image") as Bitmap?
    val beetleName=intent.getStringExtra("Beetle")


    imageCaptured2.setImageBitmap(capturedImage)
    textBeetleName.setText(beetleName)

    listView = findViewById(R.id.beetle_list)
    beetleList = mutableListOf()
    ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("beetle")

    ref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

        }

        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            if(p0!!.exists()){
                beetleList.clear()
                for (e in p0.children){
                    val beetle = e.getValue(Beetle::class.java)
                    beetleList.add(beetle!!)
                }
                val adapter = BeetleCardAdapter(this@classify,R.layout.beetle_card_item,beetleList)
                listView.adapter = adapter
            }
        }
    })
```

here is my firebase structure:

[firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X762j.png)

Comment: Start with the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase database - Retrieve data from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38219139/firebase-database-retrieve-data-from-database)

Comment: Hi Sir Alex! I want to learn retrieving using kotlin, and the documentation is using java, i dont know how to convert java to kotlin yet. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexMamo Hi! can you help me

Comment: @GianRoniDelaRosa What do you want to search and what is the expected result?

Comment: @AlexMamo I already did the connection and all, now Im writing the code to retrieve the data from firebase and the HashMap and snapshot seems not recognized. I just want the data from my firebase to be displayed on that activity as a result sir. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexMamo edited, how can I get the id and limit the data that will be retrieved.

Comment: Abot what id are you talking about and how do you want to limit?

Answer (score 0):

You can visit Google Developer recommended training here 
[Codelabs - Android](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/?cat=Android)

- I filter `Android` category for you. You can find Web / Mobile quick training here or demo to follow along.

It is written on `Java` , but the idea is still there.

And you can quickly convert your code to `Kotlin` on Android Studio and study them later if your not familiar with `Kotlin` that much. From your `Refactor` menu (If I'm not mistaken for late version below 3.2.1).

[image: Codelab Dashboard]
.

[image: Android Studio 3.2.1 Code tab]
.

From [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/start) don't forget to change the tab to `Kotlin`.

[image: Kotlin]

.
If there is no `Kotlin` tab from the documentation, try the `Firebase` from your tool, and select the `Realtime Database`. It will show you the basic code. Since I'm using `Java` , it is showing Java code. Since your default lang is `Kotlin`, 
maybe it will show `Kotlin` code.

[image: Kotlin]

.

[Kotlination - Firebase](https://grokonez.com/android/kotlin-firebase-realtime-database-readwrite-data-example-android)

Comment: Hi, there s no tab like that here https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: @GianRoniDelaRosa - I updated my answer.  It seems it is not updated from the docs, you can reference here and download the sample code as reference - https://www.raywenderlich.com/5114-firebase-tutorial-for-android-getting-started